# how to run the spring integration websocket program on different port number and how to check the heart beat

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

```
package demo ;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.Function;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.ServerWebSocketContainer;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.outbound.WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.*;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
        return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/messages").withSockJs();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageHandler webSocketOutboundAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(serverWebSocketContainer());
    }

    @Bean(name = "webSocketFlow.input")
    MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow webSocketFlow() {
        return f -> {
            Function<Message , Object> splitter = m -> serverWebSocketContainer()
                    .getSessions()
                    .keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(s -> MessageBuilder.fromMessage(m)
                            .setHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, s)
                            .build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            f.split( Message.class, splitter)
                    .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                    .handle(webSocketOutboundAdapter());
        };
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hi/{name}")
    public void send(@PathVariable String name) {
        requestChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(name).build());
    }
}
```

Here in the above program,I am able to send the message to the other register browser.But I am facing problem while I am trying to change the port number and I am unable to check the heart beat of the web socket.

Here I am accessing the server with `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/hi/Shiva Kumar`

Thanks in advance for ur precious advice

Answer (score 0):

Since this application is Spring Boot one, and we use here an embedded Servlet Container, you can follow with Boot advices on the matter to customize that environment:

> Common servlet container settings can be configured using Spring `Environment` properties. Usually you would define the properties in your `application.properties` file.
>
> Common server settings include:

```
server.port — The listen port for incoming HTTP requests.
server.address — The interface address to bind to.
server.sessionTimeout — A session timeout.
```

> See the `ServerProperties` class for a complete list.

Regarding `heartBeat`. From `SockJsServiceRegistration` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The amount of time in milliseconds when the server has not sent any
 * messages and after which the server should send a heartbeat frame to the
 * client in order to keep the connection from breaking.
 * <p>The default value is 25,000 (25 seconds).
 */
public SockJsServiceRegistration setHeartbeatTime(long heartbeatTime) {
    this.heartbeatTime = heartbeatTime;
    return this;
}
```

As long as you use `.withSockJs()` as default one your `heartbeatTime` is `25 sec`.

What do you mean regarding `check the heart beat`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

> Enable auto-configuration of the Spring Application Context, attempting to guess and configure beans that you are likely to need. Auto-configuration classes are usually applied based on your classpath and what beans you have defined. For example, If you have tomcat-embedded.jar on your classpath you are likely to want a TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory (unless you have defined your own EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean).

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setPort("1337");
        return factory;
    }

}
```